# Make SWRevealViewController as rootViewController after Sign In when it has tabbarController as sw_front objC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller, rootviewcontroller

This is my Storyboards :

[image]

Say I have a Sign In `viewController` above these and from where I want to make `SWRevealViewController` as my `rootViewController`, so that It can work perfectly. With the below code, From my `leftMenuViewController` I can select my tabBar with desired `ViewController` perfectly.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
    UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[indexPath.row];
    [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexPath.row;
    self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;
    [self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

But it is not working in `App delegate` or in `SignInViewController`.

```
- (void)checkIfUserSignedIn
{
    if ([ManagerClass getBOOLTypeUserDefaultForKey:@"isSignedIn"] == YES) {
        UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        UINavigationController *navController = tabBarController.viewControllers[0];
        [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
        self.revealViewController.rearViewRevealOverdraw = 0.0f;
        [self.revealViewController pushFrontViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
        self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    } else {

    }
}
```

It is giving this in log:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'`
Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.
Have a good day.

Comment: I did that actually. But still the same result.

Comment: Your root controller is the reveal view controller, why are you setting the tabBarController as root?

Comment: You can check if the user is signed in in AppDelegate and if not you can present your sign in controller modally, you don’t need to change the root controller.

Comment: In that case, how could I navigate user to `revealViewController`? It doesn't have any `initialize` method. And more over, will it be going to work with left menu functionality? Don't know.

Comment: You want that your left menu be accessible from sign in controller?

Comment: Yes, of course. All I want it to, when user have log in session, it will bring him to the `homeViewController`. Which is under a `navigationController`. `That navigationController` is the 1st selected tab of `tabbarController` and that `tabbarController` set as `SWRevealViewControllers` `sw_font`.

Comment: I got the solution. Please take have a look into the answer. Thanks for your effort mate. :)

Comment: Good! You are welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

All I need to do is this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:mainStoryboard bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        SWRevealViewController *controller = (SWRevealViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RevealViewControllerID"];
        [self.window setRootViewController:controller];
```

Just set `SWRevealViewController` as your `rootViewController` of the project. :)

Answer (score 0):

your answer above is right but the crash you mentioned in you question

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'`

was caused from you `storyboard` because the `SWRevealVC` in the image you posted above is not set to initial view controller, select your view controller then from Attribute Inspector check the option available `Is Initial View Controller` like [image: image below]

you should see an Arrow pointing from you `SWRevealVC`

Comment: Thanks for your response. But initially `SWRevealViewController` is not my initial `ViewController`. It is my `WelcomeViewController`. If user have signedIn session then it will change into `SWRevealViewController`. So, the thing you mentioned is actually done for `WelcomeViewController`.   
Thanks